# How do I identify which id is used from a distinct list?

Tags: mysql, distinct-values

I have the following data

```
id -> Company_name   -> chain -> subchain    -> number
1  -> account 555    -> 555   -> 555ZZ       ->  123450
2  -> account 745    -> 745   -> 745AA       ->  123451
3  -> account 745    -> 745   -> 745AA       ->  123452
4  -> account 745    -> 745   -> 745BB       ->  123453
5  -> account 745    -> 745   -> 745CC       ->  123454
6  -> account 555    -> 555   -> 555ZZ       ->  123455
```

What I am trying to do is get a list of the column "number" and the column "id" from a distinct list of the columns "chain" and "subchain".

so I need to know the number, id for those records that has the same chain and different subchain.

this code will give me the distinct list but not the number and the id of the once that are selected.

How can I handle this using MySQL?
    SELECT DISTINCT chain, subchain FROM records

The following are the result that I need

```
id -> Company_name   -> chain -> subchain    -> number
1  -> account 555    -> 555   -> 555ZZ       ->  123450
2  -> account 745    -> 745   -> 745AA       ->  123451
4  -> account 745    -> 745   -> 745BB       ->  123453
5  -> account 745    -> 745   -> 745CC       ->  123454
```

the id column is a primary column and the number is a unique value chain is a value that links/groups multiple records together. Subchain will differentiate the group to a sub group

Comment: can you show us the results you need from the data you give?

Comment: I am assuming id is your primary key column? if so you can't get one value. unless you redefine your requirement and say get the min of id or the max of the id for distinct chain and subchain.. i may be not understanding your problem.. could you please show us expected result.

Comment: @davek please review my post as I just updated it with your request

Comment: @AJP the id id a primary column.

Comment: in that case @GordonLinoff has answered it correct.. that is what i was telling you earlier.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with an arbitrary id, then just use `group by`:

```
SELECT max(id) as id, min(company_name) as company_name, chain, subchain, min(number) as number
FROM records
GROUP BY  chain, subchain;
```

If you need for the other three fields to come from the same record (say the one with the lowest id as in your example):

```
SELECT min(id) as id,
       substring_index(group_concat(company_name order by id), ',', 1) as company_name,
       chain, subchain,
       substring_index(group_concat(number order by id desc), ',', 1) + 0  as number
FROM records
GROUP BY chain, subchain;
```